# How to target an Exception more accurately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Consider the (compressed for the sake of example) code below:

```
import ics
import arrow
import requests

a = min(list(ics.Calendar(requests(get('http://asitewithcalendar.org').text).timeline.on(arrow.now())))
```

Quite a lot of things are happening here, I am fine with issues (connection, problems with the URL, ...) crashing the code but not with the following error:

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

I would like to catch that specific error: the fact that what is provided to `min()` is an empty sequence (and `pass` on it). Even more specifically, I want the other exceptions to crash, including `ValueError` ones that are not related to the empty sequence fed to `min()`.

A straightforward `try` catching `ValueError` would be fine for everything except the last constraint.

**Is there a way to say "except `ValueError` when the error is `min() arg is an empty sequence`"?**

---

*Note: I know that the code in my example is ugly - I wrote it to showcase my question so if the only answer is "impossible - you have to rewrite it to pinpoint the line you want to `try`" then fine, otherwise I am looking for general solutions*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
try:
   # Put your code to try here
   a = min(list(ics.Calendar(requests(get('http://asitewithcalendar.org').text).timeline.on(arrow.now())))

except ValueError as e:
    if str(e) == 'min() arg is an empty sequence':
        pass
    else:
        raise e
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where I would simply check the value before calling `min` rather than wait for an exception. There is no expression-level way to handle exceptions.

```
foo = list(ics.Calendar(requests(get('http://asitewithcalendar.org').text).timeline.on(arrow.now()))
if foo:
    a = min(foo)
```

It remains to decide what `a` should be if `foo` *is* empty, but you would have the same problem with a `try` statement:

```
foo = list(ics.Calendar(requests(get('http://asitewithcalendar.org').text).timeline.on(arrow.now()))

try:
    a = min(foo)
except ValueError:
    ???
```

I also wouldn't worry too much about *only* dealing with empty-sequence errors. Even if it is a different `ValueError`, `a` is just as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

how about this.

```
import numpy

a = min(list(ics.Calendar(requests(get('http://asitewithcalendar.org').text).timeline.on(arrow.now())) + [-np.inf])
```

when `-inf` has returned. list has nothing inside it.